# What do I need to set up a Entity Framework 6 Database on Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: database, database-connection

I'm new to Entity Framework and Sharepoint so bare with me.  I'm currently making a website for my work where users would be able to store entry information of their contacts and tasks.  These entries would be stored in a database that I'm making with Entity Framework 6 on Visual Studio 2015, and users would access this database through a Sharepoint 2013 site.  Here are my questions:

1. Specifically what files of the EF database would I need to include for the Sharepoint 2013 site (like an .mdf, etc.)?
2. I'm using MVC with the Entity Framework, so would this cause complications when users access the site through Sharepoint?
3. How would I get started with connecting the database to Sharepoint?

EDIT: The database consists of a few one-to-many relationships.  The Tasks and Contacts are only 2 tables from the database.